# Screenshot of a windows application running under wine (linux)

Tags: linux

Like the title says, I want to take a screenshot of a window application running under wine.  Not the entire desktop.  C would be preferred but could also use java or Pascal.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Use imagemagick's import command to grab the window and dump it to a file...

[import documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/import.php)

Wrap the call in a C system command

```
 system("import -window (your window name) capture.png").
```

Then you can access the image from the file using any of the standard image loading libraries.

Answer (score 3):

A possible way with the Linux shell:

- use xwininfo to find the window id we're looking for
- use import to dump a screenshot
- (read man import and man xwininfo for more information)

Example with wine:

```
import -window `xwininfo -root -children | grep "Wine" | awk '{print $1}'` outfile.pcx
```

Answer (score 1):

You could duplicate the functionality of ImageMagick's import command using MagickWand (C API) or Magick++ (C++ API), but calling import directly via system() as suggested by justinhj is likely the simplest approach if you don't mind distributing import with your software.