# GUI window screenshot from C/C++ to memory

Tags: c++, c, linux, screenshot

I want to do a screenshot of a GUI window from C/C++ into the memory.
It would be really nice if it's a two dimension array of RGB values or something similar.

Im at the moment searching for a Linux based solution, but would be nice if there is a platform independent solution.

Comment: By snapshot you mean screenshot, right? Or the actual memory dump of a given program?

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs yes

Comment: "Platform-independent" -- no way. To do so, you'd need a direct link into the graphics hardware, and that differs from one video card to the other. That's why different OS's have different kinds of video drivers -- to shield you from all the low-level stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could utilize *xlib* for Linux: [How do take a screenshot correctly with xlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249669/how-do-take-a-screenshot-correctly-with-xlib)

And *GDI* on Windows: [MSDN - Capturing an Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183402%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)