# Taking a screenshot of a window in C using only the X11 lib

Tags: c, linux, screenshot, x11

I am coding a raytracer engine in C using X11 on a Linux. I would like to add a screenshot feature but I can't use any other lib than the standard X11.

Is there a "simple" way to do that, or do I have to create a bmp file myself from the pixels I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will manually have to get color values of all the pixels and then convert it to a format of your choice. 
AFAIK, there is no "simple" way to do it.

You can check with this question here: [How do take a screenshot correctly with xlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249669/how-do-take-a-screenshot-correctly-with-xlib)