# Xlib - Problems taking an screenshot

Tags: c++, screenshot, xlib, ppm

I'm developing a **C++** program that takes an **screenshot** with **Xlib**.

First of all I **open the display** and I get an **XImage** pointer with **XGetImage()**.

After that I can get all the pixels with **XGetPixel()**. It **returns a decimal value**, so we have to convert it to **RGB**.

Now, the simplest method is **save as ".ppm"** image. It works fine but **something fails**:

[image: ¿Transparency?]

Some pixel's colours are wrong.

The ppm depth is **24 bits**, so I think the problem may be transparency but,

¿ Is that the problem ? ¿ **How can I get the alpha channel** ?

¿ Should I use another library like **OpenGL** ?

**Thanks!**

Comment: It seems that some windows have different color tables. Can't remember exactly (didn't use/program X11 since many years), but I remember that you can have different types of windows (color model) on the same display... Isn't this the problem? Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249669/how-do-take-a-screenshot-correctly-with-xlib

Comment: yeah it was a function fetching semi-transparent pixels cause `xgetimage`s returns undefined values for transparent pixels. did  you solve it.? then how