# Windows updating breaks drawing on them with Python Xlib

Tags: python, screenshot, x11, xlib

I'm trying to write a fun project for myself, which is a screenshot tool written in Python. I've run into an issue with one part of this, which is that I want to draw a rectangle on the screen, get the coordinates, then take a screenshot of this region. I have this working for the most part, but when the window underneath the selection updates, it breaks the drawing of the rectangle.

Here is a video displaying the issue: https://gfycat.com/EmotionalThankfulFlycatcher

I've tried reading the Xlib documentation to see if there's a way I can comfortably handle this, but wasn't able to find anything. Another alternative I could try would be to take a screenshot of the entire screen, and then take a selection of that instead of taking a region of the live desktop.

Is there anyway I can handle this, without going the route of taking a screenshot of the entire desktop and cropping that?

```
import sys
from Xlib import X, display, Xutil, xobject, Xcursorfont


class xselect:
    def __init__(self):
        # X display
        self.d = display.Display()

        # Screen
        self.screen = self.d.screen()

        # Draw on the root window (desktop surface)
        self.window = self.screen.root

    def select_region(self):

        # Set cursor to crosshair
        font = self.d.open_font('cursor')
        cursor = font.create_glyph_cursor(font, Xcursorfont.crosshair,
                                          Xcursorfont.crosshair+1,
                                          (65535, 65535, 65535), (0, 0, 0))

        self.window.grab_pointer(1, X.PointerMotionMask|X.ButtonReleaseMask|X.ButtonPressMask,
                X.GrabModeAsync, X.GrabModeAsync, X.NONE, cursor, X.CurrentTime)

        colormap = self.screen.default_colormap
        color = colormap.alloc_color(0, 0, 0)
        # Xor it because we'll draw with X.GXxor function
        xor_color = color.pixel ^ 0xffffff

        self.gc = self.window.create_gc(
            line_width = 1,
            line_style = X.LineSolid,
            fill_style = X.FillOpaqueStippled,
            fill_rule  = X.WindingRule,
            cap_style  = X.CapButt,
            join_style = X.JoinMiter,
            foreground = xor_color,
            background = self.screen.black_pixel,
            function = X.GXxor,
            graphics_exposures = False,
            subwindow_mode = X.IncludeInferiors,
        )

        done    = False
        started = False
        start   = dict(x=0, y=0)
        end     = dict(x=0, y=0)
        last    = None

        while not done:
            e = self.d.next_event()

            # Window has been destroyed, quit
            if e.type == X.DestroyNotify:
                sys.exit(0)

            # Mouse button press
            elif e.type == X.ButtonPress:
                # Left mouse button?
                if e.detail == 1:
                    start = dict(x=e.root_x, y=e.root_y)
                    started = True

                # Right mouse button?
                elif e.detail == 3:
                    sys.exit(0)

            # Mouse button release
            elif e.type == X.ButtonRelease:
                end = dict(x=e.root_x, y=e.root_y)
                if last:
                    self.draw_rectangle(start, last)
                done = True
                pass

            # Mouse movement
            elif e.type == X.MotionNotify and started:
                if last:
                    self.draw_rectangle(start, last)
                    last = None

                last = dict(x=e.root_x, y=e.root_y)
                self.draw_rectangle(start, last)
                pass

            # Keyboard key
            elif e.type == X.KeyPress:
                sys.exit(0)

            elif e.type == X.EnterNotify:
                print(' EnterNotify')

        self.d.ungrab_pointer(0)
        self.d.flush()

        coords = self.get_coords(start, end)
        if coords['width'] <= 1 or coords['height'] <= 1:
            sys.exit(0)
        else:
            return coords

    def get_coords(self, start, end):
        safe_start = dict(x=0, y=0)
        safe_end = dict(x=0, y=0)

        if start['x'] > end['x']:
            safe_start['x'] = end['x']
            safe_end['x']   = start['x']
        else:
            safe_start['x'] = start['x']
            safe_end['x']   = end['x']

        if start['y'] > end['y']:
            safe_start['y'] = end['y']
            safe_end['y']   = start['y']
        else:
            safe_start['y'] = start['y']
            safe_end['y']   = end['y']

        return {
            'start': {
                'x': safe_start['x'],
                'y': safe_start['y'],
            },
            'end': {
                'x': safe_end['x'],
                'y': safe_end['y'],
            },
            'width' : safe_end['x'] - safe_start['x'],
            'height': safe_end['y'] - safe_start['y'],
        }

    def draw_rectangle(self, start, end):
        coords = self.get_coords(start, end)
        self.window.rectangle(
            self.gc,
            coords['start']['x'],
            coords['start']['y'],
            coords['end']['x'] - coords['start']['x'],
            coords['end']['y'] - coords['start']['y']
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm still new to X11 myself, but the X11 tag on stackoverflow is pretty much dead so I'll try to answer anyway.

For taking screenshots, look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249669/how-do-take-a-screenshot-correctly-with-xlib). You want to use XGetImage, which allows you to specify the rectangle you want.

Now for drawing the rectangle, as far as I know drawing on the root window can be pretty iffy. You could instead create a fullscreen window with a transparent background. This would also allow you to give the area around the rectangle a darker tint, for example.